# bash: copy each file with a new suffix

Tags: bash, for-loop, copy

As a part of a larger problem I need to loop over (only certain, but now all for simplicity) files in a directory and make their copies with a given suffix.

Something like:

```
for f in * ; do cp $f $f_copy ; done
```

which Id like to take every file and create a copy like:
abc.txt > abc.txt_copy

or even better, before the extension:
abc_copy.txt.

The code above doesnt work. Tried quotes as well..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a permitted character in variable names. Therefore, bash searches for a variable named f_copy.

Replace

```
$f $f_copy
```

with

```
"$f" "${f}_copy"
```

or

```
"$f" "${f%.*}_copy.${f##*.}"
```

---

See: [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)